# How to get item index of a thumbnail after drag item from QListWidget Thumbnails?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

I will use drag and drop event inside my project. So, now my question is when i dragging an item from QListWidget at that time i want to get index of the thumbnail.
I am using this one code for dragging and dropping the thumbnail image.

```
void QvtkOpenGLWidgetdrag::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    QVTKOpenGLWidget::dragEnterEvent(event);
    event->accept();

}

void QvtkOpenGLWidgetdrag::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    int row;
    int col;

    if (mimeData->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")) {
        QByteArray encoded = mimeData->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
        QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        while (!stream.atEnd()) {
            QMap<int, QVariant> roleDataMap;
            stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap ;
            QIcon icon = roleDataMap.value(1).value<QIcon>();
            m_pixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes().first());
            update();
        }
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
    else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

Any help is very useful for me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you are dragging in the Qlist? or out from the list??

Comment: i am draging from QListWidget and drop inside QopenGLWidget view

Comment: here an example of how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the method **currentIndex()** in the ListWidget, then check if that is valid and if so, get the row value... (note that they begin at 0)

example

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidget->addItem("A");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("B");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("C");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    auto index = ui->listWidget->currentIndex();
    if (index.isValid())
    {
       std::cout << "row: " << index.row() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: All drag and drop event function is written in another class(inside draganddrop.cpp) and QListWidget object is available inside mainwindow.cpp class. I am draging the item from dradanddrop.cpp class and inside that class I need the item.

Comment: then use/connect signal slots

Comment: give me some idea how to use it, bcz i am taken all the function inside the dragandrop.cpp as protected .

Comment: i will added some piece of code where i want to use that item